# Is the following code Composition if not then how to make it composite?

Tags: java, oop, composition, relation

Just begin to learn OOPs concepts and i am bit confused in relations, Aggregation and Composition 
I wanna know whether the following code is Composition or not

```
class Person {

String name;
Dob dob;

public Person(String name, int date, String month, int year) {
    this.name = name;
    dob = new Dob(date, month, year);
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public Dob getDob() {
    return dob;
    }

}
```

---

```
class Dob {

int date, year;
String month;

public Dob(int date, String month, int year) {
    this.date = date;
    this.year = year;
    this.month = month;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return date + " " + month + " " + year;
}

}
```

---

```
public class JavaApplication6 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Person person = new Person("omar", 4, "march", 1996);

    System.out.println(person.name + " " + person.dob);

}

}
```

if it is not Composition the how to achieve it by considering the same example
Thanks you

Comment: Yes it is composition. Person is composed using DOB

Comment: but DOB is not bound by person , i can still make it as a separate object

Answer (score 1):

Aggregation and Composition make me think to UML concepts : the first one is a strong relationship between an entity and another while the second one is a still stronger relationship between an entity and another.
For example the compositor deletion triggers the deletion of the composed  entity in the composition relationship but not in the aggregation relationship.

In Java, only the notion of composition is commonly used and it doesn't mean the same thing.
It means that an object/class is composed of another one. It is a synonym of wrapper.
We often oppose it to inheritancy.

In your case, `Person` doesn't inherit from `Dob` but owns a field of `Dob`. So it composes/wraps it.

The UML composition is not necessary easy to translate in terms of Java objects.
It is more natural as you work with an ORM where the notion of row deletion and `on delete cascade` make sense.

For plain Java objects, the deletion/collect of the objects is performed by the garbage collector (GC).
So while the `Dob` instance is referenced by another object, it will be alive.
To ensure its deletion you should probably make the `Dob` field not accessible to any other object but the `Person` instance that composes it.
To achieve it you could remove the getter in `Person` that returns the `Dob` instance.
In this way, as soon the `Person` is eligible to be collected by the GC, it will also be the case for the `Dob` instance that is only referenced by the `Person` object.

Comment: dont i need to bound Dob object by person to get instantiated ? i mean i can make Dob object even if Person does not exists Thanks

Comment: In terms of Java objects, as you want to establish the composition relationship, you should indeed let only Person to instantiate the Dob. In terms of ORM, it doesn't matter as the object will finally represented a line in a database table.